# Google Satellite layer does not allow zooming in and out in QGIS

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

Google Satellite layer does not allow zooming in or out in QGIS instead the kml layers are the moving around. please help how do i fix this?

Comment: Please provide some more details. What CRS are your layers in? What CRS is the project in? What version of QGIS are you using? Can you provide some screen shots of your problem to help illustrate?

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers plugin is outdated. Use QuickMapServices plugin instead.

- The plugin link: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/
- Basemaps repository - https://qms.nextgis.com/about
- Screencast - https://youtu.be/9Y0_uUH7zns