# Google Maps (street, physical, satellite) layers stay fixed on zoom/pan in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, google-maps, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm using QGIS 1.8 and Openlayers plugin 1.1.0 to work with Google Maps as basemap (I need to use this old versions for both QGIS and plugin). All was working OK, but from some days Google Maps (street, physical, satellite) loaded with OL plugin stay fixed when I zoom or pan, so my other layers move but map stays fixed. Other maps (Bing, Apple, ...) work perfectly. Any help on this? Is it a googlemaps issue? Is it due to the plugin? I do not how to tackle this issue.

I have been searching for information about it and this seems to be related:
[Google Satellite layer does not allow zooming in and out in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252336/google-satellite-layer-does-not-allow-zooming-in-and-out-in-qgis/252498?newreg=ccb0b95e21c34cc3b6f606d966af7ea3)
 but in any case I cannot change to QuickMapServices plugin instead as proposed, as it needs QGIS 2.x. I am restricted to QGIs 1.8 and OL plugin 1.1.0.

Note: I have a quasy-migrated version of the same project on QGIS 2.18 and OpenLayers 1.4.1, and it still works, so I do not know if the issue is only with the old version of QGIS, the old version of Openlayers plugin or is a GoogleMaps issue. Old project stop working in August.